# How to update a row with part of the string from another table - mysql?

Tags: mysql

I need to update a `table1` with a value from `table2` on a condition of some first 3 characters matched.

So I did:

```
update lead_db l1
inner join option_nat n1 on n1.nat_title=left(l1.ld_naty,3)
set l1.ld_ncode=n1.nat_id
```

But there's nothing happened. Please tell me what's wrong i've done here!

Comment: Is `nat_title` EXACTLY equal to the 3 characters of the other string? Show us examples of their values

Comment: No `nat_title` is longer than 3. But I need to use only first 3 chars from `ld_naty` to search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this and let me know if it doesn't work.

```
update lead_db l1, option_nat n1
set l1.ld_ncode=n1.nat_id
where n1.nat_title regexp left(l1.ld_naty,3)
```

Comment: Your solution is working. Just change from `=` to `regexp` - Cheers!

Comment: Yes right ... just read your comment that `nat_title` is longer than 3. Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UPDATE lead_db l1
INNER JOIN option_nat n1
ON n1.nat_title LIKE CONCAT(LEFT(l1.ld_naty,3), '%')
SET l1.ld_ncode = n1.nat_id
```

Because if their values are, for example `ABCDEF` and `ABC123`, the comparison between `ABCDEF` and `ABC` is false! But if you try with `ABCDEF LIKE "ABC%"` it will works...

Answer (score 0):

The reason why nothing is happening is because the database cannot do the join you are telling it to do. If `nat_title` is longer than 3 characters (like you said in your comment) then there isn't anything to join.

Example: Let's say `nat_title` contains the value "This is an example" and `ld_naty` contains only "Thi". You are now trying to join "This is an example" on "Thi", which obviously doesn't work, because it's not the same.

You need something like this:

```
UPDATE lead_db l1
INNER JOIN option_nat n1 on n1.nat_title LIKE CONCAT(LEFT(l1.ld_naty,3), '%')
SET l1.ld_ncode = n1.nat_id
```

But be sure that this is really what you want. Because now "This is an example" would be joined on *anything* that starts with the letters "Thi" (and it's not even case sensitive, so "tHi" would be a valid join as well).